# Sum hours in 00:00 format form mySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table column in Varchar2 data type with data in format '00:00'.Now, I want to add total figures of this column using SUM() function.Please suggest the ways to add up total figures in single select statement.

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>Customer Code<th/>
<th>Hours<th/>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1<td/>
<td>22:30<td/>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2<td/>
<td>11:20<td/>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2<td/>
<td>10:20<td/>
</tr>


</table>
```

I need single select query which return Customer Code and sum of Total hours of
against each customer

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that your database schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `code` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `content` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `code`, `content`) VALUES
    ('1', '1', '10:30'),
    ('2', '1', '5:40'),
    ('3', '2', '22:30'),
    ('4', '3', '15:20');
```

Then, you can get the result as:

```
SELECT 
    code,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CAST(content AS TIME)))) AS total
FROM
    test
GROUP BY code;
```

Which will give you

```
code    total
1       16:10:00
2       22:30:00
3       15:20:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Above ans is much optimised , but you can do the same using ,

```
SELECT code,Replace(ROUND((SUM(substr(content,1,2) * 60) + SUM(substr(content,4,5)) ) / 60 , 2) ,'.',':') as total_hrs FROM test group by code
```

if you dont want to use much of the pre defined functions this may help.